# Group BY clause to temporary table

Tags: sql

I am beginner in SQL trying to group by a result

```
SELECT 
    API.PROJECTNUMBER, Project.ProjectName, Project.PROJMGRID, Staff.Email
INTO 
    #TEMPUnmatchedProjectWithSMoD
FROM 
    {ProjectsIncidentsIntegration} API WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN 
    {Project} project WITH(NOLOCK) ON Project.ProjectNumber = API.PROJECTNUMBER
JOIN 
    {COMMON_STAFF} Staff WITH(NOLOCK) ON Staff.EmplId = Project.PROJMGRID
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM @DBName.DBO.NCompasS_TBL_SMoDIncident SMoD WITH(NOLOCK) 
                WHERE SMoD.ProjectCode = API.PROJECTNUMBER)

SELECT * 
FROM #TEMPUnmatchedProjectWithSMoD
GROUP BY Project.PROJMGRID
```

I get an error:

> Database returned the following error:
> Error in advanced query UnmatchedProjectWithSMoD2: The multi-part identifier "Project.PROJMGRID" could not be bound.

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TEMPUnmatchedProjectWithSMoD
GROUP BY Project.PROJMGRID ;
```

There are two major issues:

1. `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is not correct.  What should be done with the columns that are not aggregation keys?  You might have some idea.  SQL generates an error.
2. `Project` is not defined.

It is quite unclear what this code is supposed to be doing, so I cannot suggest anything useful.  You can just select all rows from the temporary table using:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM #TEMPUnmatchedProjectWithSMoD p;
```